# PHP and MS Access odd query results for float values

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

My development computer (Win7 Pro) is running PHP 5.5.11 under Apache using XAMPP, and running MS Access 2013. The production server (WinServer 2012) is running PHP 5.6 under IIS 8, and running MS Access 2010. The data in the development and production databases is, of course, identical.

I am using a PHP page to generate a production report, which includes a calculation of feetProduced * weightPerFt to determine the total weight of material produced at various intervals. The same select query in my PHP code (using PDO_ODBC) gives different results when executed on the production server vs my development computer... specifically when querying weightPerFt, which is a float value (a single in Access). Nearly all values that are < 0.1 return in the select query results as E-2, and it is treated as zero in my later calculations. Others are 1.2345E-1, etc.. which is fine. But on my development PC, I always get the proper float value returned (2.334E-2, 2.23E-1, or whatever).

Anybody seen this before and/or have any ideas as to the cause? Perhaps due to different PHP version and/or PDO driver? If so, the older one seems better!

EDIT: To clarify, I am getting a different result from the same query to the same single field BEFORE any calculations are done. For example, imagine I have a table with a single column (wtPerFt) and a single row with the value 0.025 in that column. Using PHP, if I run "SELECT wtPerFt from myTable" on my development PC, I get "2.5E-2," but on the production server, I get "E-2" (evaluates as zero). Those are the values printed to the screen with print_r(). Same query, identical database (copy), different computer.

I have implemented a workaround by using

```
SELECT weightPerFt * 100 AS weightPerFt...
```

and then compensating in my later calculations with

```
lbsProduced = feetProduced * (weightPerFt / 100)
```

so this is not a critical problem, it's just irritating me.

Comment: you're using floats. everything is approximated with floats, and you can't use quality tests, only "close enough" tests. e.g. `float1 = float2` isn't useful, while `abs(float1 - float2) <= $tolerance` IS useful.

Comment: I thought that was the issue at first, but then I discovered that the error is occurring BEFORE any calculations are done. I actually get different query results from the same single field before any calculations are done on it. I'll clarify with an edit to the original post.

Comment: May be a problem with 32bit/64bit floats. Or a different ODBC driver on each system.

Comment: You might consider trying a little test using [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) and a `COM("ADODB.Connection")` object to see if you get consistent results on both machines. Neither the old PHP `odbc_` functions nor PDO_ODBC work particularly well with the Access ODBC drivers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out when I get the chance. Priorities have moved me away from this for now....

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson, you were correct! I finally got back to this issue and tested connecting with COM vs. PDO. It looks like I'll have to learn to use COM instead as long as my employer is using MS Access. Using a COM object gives me a much more accurate result when reading small float values from the database. Where my test-query result from PDO gave me "E-4," which was treated as zero when used in calculations in my PHP code, the COM object gave me "0.00096619420219213," which is the actual value in the database.